# Change background colour of an active div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a drop down menu.I wanna change the background color of active span tag, which contains the arrow image. And on click of any dropdown option, it  should close and that option should come in the menu.

example:- if i click on option 'DROP ITEM 2' option , it should replace the 'ITEM NAME'.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
  function t(t) {
    e(t).bind("click", function(t) {
      t.preventDefault();
      e(this).parent().fadeOut()
    })
  }
  e(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
    $("#rotate_sign").css({
      'background-color': 'green'
    });
    var t = e(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown_menu").is(":hidden");
    e(".button-dropdown .dropdown_menu").hide();
    e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active");
    if (t) {
      e(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown_menu").toggle().parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-toggle").addClass("active")
    }
  });
  e(document).bind("click", function(t) {
    var n = e(t.target);
    if (!n.parents().hasClass("button-dropdown"))
      e(".button-dropdown .dropdown_menu").hide();
  });
  e(document).bind("click", function(t) {
    var n = e(t.target);
    if (!n.parents().hasClass("button-dropdown"))
      e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active");
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav .button-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.nav .button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
  font-size: 7.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 2.33;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #666667;
}

.nav .button-dropdown .dropdown_items {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
  font-size: 7.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 2.33;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #666667;
  border-bottom: solid 0.5px #e4e4e4;
}

.border_bottom_none {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ffffff;
}

.nav li a span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #999;
  height: 26.5px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.dropdown_menu {
  z-index: 1000;
  float: left;
  /*min-width: 160px;*/
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.nav li .dropdown_menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 0.5px 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
}

.nav li .dropdown_menu.active {
  display: block;
}

.nav li .dropdown_menu a {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

div.custom-table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

div.custom-table-row {
  display: table-row
}

div.custom-table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px;
}

.custom-table-row>.custom-table-cell {
  height: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

div.table-cell-data {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

div.table-cell-data.right-align {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

div.custom-table.brand-portal-panel div.custom-table-row div.custom-table-cell {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

div.custom-table.brand-portal-panel div.custom-table-row div.custom-table-cell img.brand-icon {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div.custom-table.brand-portal-panel div.custom-table-row div.custom-table-cell:first-child {
  min-width: 5%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.custom-table.brand-portal-panel div.custom-table-row div.custom-table-cell:nth-child(2) {
  width: 45%;
}

div.custom-table.brand-portal-panel div.custom-table-row div.custom-table-cell:nth-child(3) {
  width: 25%;
}

div.custom-table.brand-portal-panel div.custom-table-row div.custom-table-cell:nth-child(4) {
  width: 15%;
}

div.custom-table.brand-portal-panel div.custom-table-row div.custom-table-cell:nth-child(5) {
  width: 10%;
}

.sign_rotate {
  height: 20px;
  width: 19px;
}

.sign_rotate img {
  width: 100%;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-table brand-portal-panel">
  <div class="custom-table-row">
    <div class="custom-table-cell">
      <div class="table-cell-data">
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-table-cell">
      <div class="table-cell-data">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="button-dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
                                                ITEM name <span id="rotate_sign" class="sign_rotate"><img src="images/dropdown.png" alt="dropdown"/></span>
            
                                            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown_menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items">
                                                        Drop Item 1
                                                    </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items">
                                                        Drop Item 2
                                                    </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items border_bottom_none">
                                                        Drop Item 3
                                                    </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-table-cell">
      <div class="table-cell-data">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="button-dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
                                                DATE IMPORTED <span id="rotate_sign" class="sign_rotate"><img src="images/dropdown.png" alt="dropdown"/></span>
                                            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown_menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items">
                                                        Drop Item 1
                                                    </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items">
                                                        Drop Item 2
                                                    </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items border_bottom_none">
                                                        Drop Item 3
                                                    </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-table-cell">
      <div class="table-cell-data">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="button-dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
                                                CATOGERY <span id="rotate_sign" class="sign_rotate"><img src="images/dropdown.png" alt="dropdown"/></span>
                                            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown_menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items">
                                                        Drop Item 1
                                                    </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items">
                                                        Drop Item 2
                                                    </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items border_bottom_none">
                                                        Drop Item 3
                                                    </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-table-cell">
      <div class="table-cell-data right-align">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="button-dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
                                                STATUS <span id="rotate_sign" class="sign_rotate"><img src="images/dropdown.png" alt="dropdown"/></span>
                                            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown_menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items">
                                                        Drop Item 1
                                                    </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items">
                                                        Drop Item 2
                                                    </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items border_bottom_none">
                                                        Drop Item 3
                                                    </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you not cut down on the source code and only include the relevant source?

Comment: Create a functional example of your code, and we probably can suggest a CSS-only fix for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place the text "item name " in a span with an id named `label1`
and add the following

```
  e(".dropdown_menu").click(function(event){
  e("#label1").text(event.target.textContent.trim());
  })
```

Snippet below

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
  function t(t) {
    e(t).bind("click", function(t) {
      t.preventDefault();
      e(this).parent().fadeOut()
    })
  }
  e(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
    $("#rotate_sign").css({
      'background-color': 'green'
    });
    var t = e(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown_menu").is(":hidden");
    e(".button-dropdown .dropdown_menu").hide();
    e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active");
    if (t) {
      e(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown_menu").toggle().parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-toggle").addClass("active")
    }
  });
  e(document).bind("click", function(t) {
    var n = e(t.target);
    if (!n.parents().hasClass("button-dropdown"))
      e(".button-dropdown .dropdown_menu").hide();
  });
  e(document).bind("click", function(t) {
    var n = e(t.target);
    if (!n.parents().hasClass("button-dropdown"))
      e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active");

  });
  e(".dropdown_menu").click(function(event) {
    e("#label1").text(event.target.textContent.trim());
      console.log(this);
  })
  e(".table-cell-data").click(function(ev){
  var that=this;
  e(".table-cell-data").each(function(){

  if(this.classList.contains("color_me") && this!=that){
  this.classList.remove("color_me");
  }

  })
    this.classList.add("color_me")
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav .button-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.nav .button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
  font-size: 7.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 2.33;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #666667;
}

.nav .button-dropdown .dropdown_items {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
  font-size: 7.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 2.33;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #666667;
  border-bottom: solid 0.5px #e4e4e4;
}

.border_bottom_none {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ffffff;
}

.nav li a span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #999;
  height: 26.5px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.dropdown_menu {
  z-index: 1000;
  float: left;
  /*min-width: 160px;*/
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.nav li .dropdown_menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 0.5px 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
}

.nav li .dropdown_menu.active {
  display: block;
}

.nav li .dropdown_menu a {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

div.custom-table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

div.custom-table-row {
  display: table-row
}

div.custom-table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px;
}

.custom-table-row>.custom-table-cell {
  height: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

div.table-cell-data {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

div.table-cell-data.right-align {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

div.custom-table.brand-portal-panel div.custom-table-row div.custom-table-cell {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

div.custom-table.brand-portal-panel div.custom-table-row div.custom-table-cell img.brand-icon {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div.custom-table.brand-portal-panel div.custom-table-row div.custom-table-cell:first-child {
  min-width: 5%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.custom-table.brand-portal-panel div.custom-table-row div.custom-table-cell:nth-child(2) {
  width: 45%;
}

div.custom-table.brand-portal-panel div.custom-table-row div.custom-table-cell:nth-child(3) {
  width: 25%;
}

div.custom-table.brand-portal-panel div.custom-table-row div.custom-table-cell:nth-child(4) {
  width: 15%;
}

div.custom-table.brand-portal-panel div.custom-table-row div.custom-table-cell:nth-child(5) {
  width: 10%;
}

.sign_rotate {
  height: 20px;
  width: 19px;
}

.sign_rotate img {
  width: 100%;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.color_me{
background:green;
color:white;
}
#rotate_sign{
background:transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-table brand-portal-panel">
  <div class="custom-table-row">
    <div class="custom-table-cell">
      <div class="table-cell-data">
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-table-cell">
      <div class="table-cell-data">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="button-dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
              <span id="label1"> ITEM name <span><span id="rotate_sign" class="sign_rotate"><img src="images/dropdown.png" alt="dropdown"/></span>

            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown_menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items">Drop Item 1 </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items">Drop Item 2 </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items border_bottom_none">Drop Item </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-table-cell">
      <div class="table-cell-data">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="button-dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
                                                DATE IMPORTED <span id="rotate_sign" class="sign_rotate"><img src="images/dropdown.png" alt="dropdown"/></span>
                                            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown_menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items">Drop Item 1 </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items">Drop Item 2 </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items border_bottom_none">Drop Item 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-table-cell">
      <div class="table-cell-data">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="button-dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
                                                CATOGERY <span id="rotate_sign" class="sign_rotate"><img src="images/dropdown.png" alt="dropdown"/></span>
                                            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown_menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items">Drop Item 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items">Drop Item 2 </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items border_bottom_none">Drop Item 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-table-cell">
      <div class="table-cell-data right-align">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="button-dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
                                                STATUS <span id="rotate_sign" class="sign_rotate"><img src="images/dropdown.png" alt="dropdown"/></span>
                                            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown_menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items">Drop Item 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items">Drop Item 2 </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_items border_bottom_none">Drop Item 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May u plzz make the active dropdown green??